# Polygons will not buffer in ArcMap and instead give WARNING 000117: Warning empty output generated?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, warning-000117

I have been trying to buffer 15 polygons (-15m) in ArcMap.  I did a batch buffer and 13 polygons worked fine, the other 2 have not buffered, an error occurs:
WARNING 000117: Warning empty output generated.
Executed (Buffer) successfully.
End Time: Fri Jul 06 18:58:32 2012 (Elapsed Time: 1.00 seconds)

All the input polygons are similar with full attribute tables so the output should not be empty for these 2!

Answer (score 6):

***If the negative buffer distance is large enough to collapse the polygon to nothing, a null geometry will be generated. A warning message will be given, and any null geometry features will not be written to the output feature class. (ESRI)***

Any chance that some of your polygons when buffered by a negative value would result in a null geometry?

You can control and flag this programatically with ArcObjects (not sure about python) by trapping the error and skipping (not creating a feature for) the "culprit" polygons.

Answer (score 3):

Just a wild guess, related to bugs like [Polygons converted from lines have a negative area](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31649) where ArcGIS confuses the "outside" and "inside" of the polygon border.

- Export your data to a new shapefile.
- Run the [Repair Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003v000000) tool on this new shapefile.
- Buffer this new shapefile.

Does that fix things?

Comment: Is the polygon more than 15m wide? If not it will collapse on itself and result in empty geometry.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why?  I was under the impression that a 15m buffer could be applied to an arbitrarily small line, point, or polygon without becoming invalid.

Comment: I see, I missed the "(-15)" = "negative 15m"